# Which is the set for transfinite ordinals $\omega$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let me write down my train of thoughts to make my question clear.

If the collection of elements $\{0,1,2,3,....\}$ is defined as the set $\mathbb{N}$. Then if $\omega$ is the first transfinite ordinal. Is there a corresponding definition (set) for the following collection of elements:

$\{\omega, \omega +1, \omega +2, ...\}$

And/or

$\{0,1,2,...,\omega, \omega +1, \omega +2, ...\}$

And/or

$\{\omega, \omega +1, \omega +2, ..., \omega^2, \omega^2 +1, \omega^2 +2, ..., \omega^3, \omega^3 +1, \omega^3 +2, ..., \omega^{\omega}\}$

And/or

$\{0,1,2,..., \omega, \omega +1, \omega +2, ..., \omega^2, \omega^2 +1, \omega^2 +2, ..., \omega^3, \omega^3 +1, \omega^3 +2, ..., \omega^{\omega}\}$ ?

P.S. If you can write down your sources I would deeply appreciate it

Comment: Note that $\omega^1 = \omega$, so you've written some numbers twice in your last two sets.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're looking for here. Are you wanting definitions in primitive notation?

Comment: @celtschk : You are right, I edited the redundancy. Thanks for the pointing it out.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine : HenningMakholm is nailing my question down with his answers and replies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the usual development of set theory, each ordinal is represented as the set of all smaller ordinals. (In particular, this makes $\omega$ a name for the set more elementarily known as $\mathbb N$). Therefore, the set
$$\{0,1,2,...,\omega, \omega +1, \omega +2, ...\}$$
is the ordinal $\omega\cdot 2$, also known as $\omega+\omega$.

The best notation for
$$ \{\omega, \omega +1, \omega +2, ...\}$$
would be $\omega\cdot 2 \setminus \omega$.

The set of all ordinals up to *and including* $\omega^\omega$ is $\omega^\omega+1$.

Comment: Thanks @HenningMakholm that clears almost everything. Just a couple of doubts in line with your answer.

Comment: Is there a more elementary set to denote $\omega^{\omega}$?. And, hence would it be OK to write a statement like $n \in \omega^2$ to make reference to any of the elements $\{1,2,3,..., \omega , \omega +1, \omega +3, ... \}$

Comment: @HavingFun: There is no simpler name for $\omega^\omega$. I don't think $\{1,2,3,\ldots, \omega , \omega +1, \omega +3, \ldots\}$ is a particularly good way to describe $\omega^2$; how would you see from those "$\ldots$" that you're not merely speaking about $\omega\cdot 2$?

Comment: You are right about the imprecision on my notation, just to make my question clearer and avoid imprecision I would use a simpler example. So can I say $n \in  5$ to denote  that $n$ is an integer less than $5$ ?. I know this example is silly, but I want to know if it is possible to use that logic for $n \in \omega ^2$

Comment: @HavingFun: You can do that, though $n\in 5$ will probably only be understood in a context where you have explicitly made clear that you're talking about the Von Neumann ordinals. In general, people tend to write $n<5$ and $n<\omega^2$ more often than $\in$; this is considered easier to understand. In particular, $n\in\omega^2$ would be at risk of being misunderstood as saying that $n$ is something like $\langle 42,7\rangle$ (an ordered pair) rather than something like $\omega\cdot 42+7$ (an ordinal).

Comment: That completes all my doubts.  My question can be now closed. Thank you so much for all your support everyone.

Comment: @HavingFun Rather than close the question, I think you should accept this answer if it cleared up the issue.